# Async WebRequest Timeout Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

I'm wondering what the "right" way of timing out an HttpWebRequest is on Windows Phone7?

I've been reading about ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject() but this can't be used as WaitHandles throw a Not implemented exception at run time.

I've also been looking at ManualReset events but A) Don't understand them properly and B) Don't understand how blocking the calling thread is an acceptable way to implement a time out on an Async request.

Here's my existing code sans timeout, can someone please show me how I would add a timeout to this?

```
public static void Get(Uri requestUri, HttpResponseReceived httpResponseReceivedCallback, ICredentials credentials, object userState, bool getResponseAsString = true, bool getResponseAsBytes = false)
                {
                    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);

                    httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
                    httpWebRequest.Credentials = credentials;

                    var httpClientRequestState = new JsonHttpClientRequestState(null, userState, httpResponseReceivedCallback, httpWebRequest, getResponseAsString, getResponseAsBytes);

                    httpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(ResponseReceived, httpClientRequestState);
                }

private static void ResponseReceived(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
      var httpClientRequestState = asyncResult.AsyncState as JsonHttpClientRequestState;

       Debug.Assert(httpClientRequestState != null, "httpClientRequestState cannot be null. Fatal error.");

       try
       {
           var webResponse  = (HttpWebResponse)httpClientRequestState.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult);

       }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic Async Timeout Pattern for C#:

```
public static T SafeLimex<T>(Func<T> F, int Timeout, out bool Completed)   
   {
       var iar = F.BeginInvoke(null, new object());
       if (iar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(Timeout))
       {
           Completed = true;
           return F.EndInvoke(iar);
       }
         F.EndInvoke(iar); //not calling EndInvoke will result in a memory leak
         Completed = false;
       return default(T);
   }
```

Not sure if this will work on Windows Phone 7.
 You might want to take a look at this -
[Exposing asynchronous features to client code: Windows Phone 7](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/windows-phone-7/async-wp7.aspx)

Comment: I don't understand the use of WaitOne though - From MSDN - "Blocks the current thread until the current WaitHandle receives a signal." - It defeats the whole purpose of the async pattern to block the calling thread for the duration of the async operation.

Comment: Try to wrap the call inside another thread. So the calling thread will be blocked and main app will remain responsive.

Comment: There must be a better way async != new thread. I don't want a new thread to be hanging around for each async web request in the event that a timeout may or may not occur.

Comment: No thread is hanging around. Threads started by BeginInvoke() are managed by .NET ThreadPool. So you should not worry about those. Just make sure you call the EndInvoke. I have added a link for you to look at.